# Covert string of dates to date time M-D format

Tags: python, string, datetime, plot

I have a list of dates and I want python to recognize that these are dates that can be plotted continuously along the y-axis, for example.

```
data = ["2-22", "2-29", "3-7", "3-14", "3-21", "3-28", "4-4", "4-11", "4-18", "4-25", "5-2", "5-9", "5-16", "5-23", "5-30", "6-6", "6-13", "6-20", "6-27", "7-4", "7-11", "7-18", "7-25", "8-08", "8-22", "8-29", "9-5", "9-12", "9-19", "9-26", "10-3", "10-10", "10-17", "10-24", "10-31", "11-7", "11-14", "11-21", "1-23", "1-30", "2-06", "3-13", "3-27", "6-19", "6-26"]
```

Should I use `datetime.strptime` or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%y').date() for date in data]
```

However in your original list you have invalid dates such as `4-4`, if that is April 2004 it should be written as `4-04`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, we split each item inbetween the - then reassemble it the other way around with a -

```
data = ["2-22", "2-29", "3-7", "3-14", "3-21", "3-28", "4-4", "4-11", "4-18", "4-25", "5-2", "5-9", "5-16", "5-23", "5-30", "6-6", "6-13", "6-20", "6-27", "7-4", "7-11", "7-18", "7-25", "8-08", "8-22", "8-29", "9-5", "9-12", "9-19", "9-26", "10-3", "10-10", "10-17", "10-24", "10-31", "11-7", "11-14", "11-21", "1-23", "1-30", "2-06", "3-13", "3-27", "6-19", "6-26"]
for Date in data:
 data = Date.split("-")
 print(data[1]+"-"+data[0])
```